# Please take away the Google juice from rads.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, google

[This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22T[]%22):

```
site:stackoverflow.com "T[]"
```

comes up with absolute garbage; it isn't clear why these things are hosted on a stackoverflow.com subdomain to begin with, since they have nothing to do with programming (they aren't even on-topic as paid advertisements). They certainly shouldn't be appearing in search listings (above *real* Q&A content, no less).

[image]

Please set up `robots.txt` or the modern equivalent to turn indexers/crawlers away from rads.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: As a workaround you can add `-rads` [to the search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22T[]%22#q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22T%5B%5D%22+-rads) for now.

Comment: Apologies for the infinite noobness, but what does googling a site with "T[]" return?

Comment: Well, return types shall not be arrays, so that search would be ill-formed.

Comment: To search for special characters on SO you should probably use a search engine that doesn't strip them from your search terms. I'd suggest http://symbolhound.com/ which was created by another SO user and indexes the SE network or at least SO.

Comment: I tried this today, and get a perfect selection, e.g. "how to get class instance of generics type T - Stack Overflow"

Comment: @DieterMenne: Must be geolocation-driven, the link in my question gives the same garbage results today.

Comment: @l4mpi: The exact search is really beside the point.  StackOverflow should not be making proxied pages available for crawling.

Comment: @BenVoigt I wasn't really addressing your point and I agree that the pages should not be indexed; I simply wanted to suggest a better and little-known alternative for search terms like this.

Comment: .. a symbol-aware search such as [Stack Overflow's own](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22T%5B%5D%22), perhaps? Google may be capable of returning everything from A to Z but sometimes you need a bit more.

Answer (score 38):

`rads.stackoverflow.com` is the rewritten [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) for a link to Amazon.

If one takes the URL `http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882` and pastes it into a post with a nice name you get: [clean code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) which is actually the link `http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882` once the [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) parser gets through with it.

Look closely at that URL and you will see that its been rewritten to go through Stack Exchange's affiliate program. This program likely predates Stack Exchange.  Changing the URL when other sites were created would have been a mess.  So, it's in Stack Overflow's domain.

But yes, robots crawling it is likely an oversight.

Comment: Yes, I figured it was a forwarder adding the affiliate ID.  But proxy/forwarder/whatever shouldn't be eligible for inclusion in search results.  To be honest, I think they ought to be `nofollow` as well.

Comment: Google policies recommend using `rel="nofollow"` on affiliate links, so yes, they definitely should @BenVoigt.

Comment: `Rel='nofollow'` will make them go away on Google after a week or two

Comment: It's the poster's responsibility to make sure that this doesn't happen. One way is to replace `amazon.com` with `smile.amazon.com`.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi the poster is doing the right thing by posting a proper, simple link to Amazon.  It helps stack exchange by allowing them to rewrite it into the affiliate program and make a few cents off of a purchase (if there is one) and helps keep the lights on at Stack Exchange.  The problem is that part of the automated systems that work within Stack Exchange have overlooked google crawling it and what that does to search results. That needs to get fixed.  But its *good* that Stack Exchange does this otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

As Ben mentioned, this must be some geolocation problem. From Germany, I see this:

[image: T stack]

Cannot be better.

Comment: Now go to the next page, etc. The `rads` results are not on page 1.