# rads.stackoverflow.com links are not HTTPS

Tags: bug, ssl

I find two HTTPS-related issues. I hope these can be improved:

Links to Amazon are automatically converted to a [rewritten URL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277809/6581662): `http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/<id>`, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321563840). This link doesn't use HTTPS, even though rads.stackoverflow.com does respond to HTTPS requests. Please use HTTPS links if possible.

Also `http(s)://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/<id>` redirects to `http://www.amazon.com/...`. Since Amazon now fully supports HTTPS, you can actually make it redirect to `https://www.amazon.com` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New generated links are using HTTPS now. Old links are not updated though. Thank you for fixing this issue!