# Links to amazon.com are converted to rads.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, support

I [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600976/issue-with-regular-expressions-while-parsing-source-code) that links to `amazon.com` are being converted to `rads.stackoverflow.com` and then redirected to the original destination, i.e.:

This:

- [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PWCJZJ6?pf_rd_p=2d1ab404-3b11-4c97-b3db-48081e145e35&pf_rd_r=0PF9KX04Y9GAPGCXBDAP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PWCJZJ6)

Is converted into :

- https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PWCJZJ6

Can someone please explain me why this is happening?

---

P.S.: I  found this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355958/rads-stackoverflow-com-links-are-not-https), but afaik it's not duplicated.

Comment: See answer on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277809, and on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26964/165483, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87136/165483

Comment: They make some money out of links to amazon, but in order to do that they have to convert them before.

Comment: That seems... https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/wrong.

Comment: @Trilarion I cannot see any tracking cookie or affiliate id being added to the URL during redirection.